# Как отключить auto resizing в figma

Tags: resize, figma

Когда тянешь в правую сторону элемента также тянуться врпаво - как это отключить?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Просто выбери тут Frame для группы в которой лежат элементы

[image: Frame]